What happens to my read-replica database in failover mode?
I have a few basic questions about Azure failover. I am new to failover. I've been reading the literature and I'm ready to give this a shot. Before I take the plunge, I'd like to have a better understanding of how this will work.
We have a primary database on a server on one region, let's call that server DBPrime. We recently created a read-replica on a server in a different region. Our first step was to offload read workloads to the read-replica. Let's call that server DBRead.
We now want to take the next step and set up failover. If I understand the literature correctly, I don't need a third server for failover purposes. Rather, I can use the read-replica server to function as my alternate server for failover?
Here is my understanding of what will happen if failover is triggered. Please let me know if I'm correct about each of these statements, or if I'm not understanding this properly.

Azure will swap server names so that DBRead is now DBPrime and vice versa.
The new DBPrime will transition from read-only mode to read-write.
Application references to DBPrime will seamlessly access the new DBPrime
Workloads referencing DBRead will not be able to access the server because that server is currently down (which triggered the failover to begin with).

(We can discuss separately what happens when we come out of failover. Bu no sense in getting to that until I understand what happens when we go in to failover mode.)
Thank you for your advice!

In the Azure portal on the Failover Group tab, there should be two endpoints, one that is for read-write workloads and one for read-only workloads (.secondary.).  If you have your read-only workloads using the read-only endpoint then they will switch seamlessly to the now secondary node.
But yes, assuming that all of the SIDs for the logins match then everything should be pretty seamless for you.  This is the same care that you need to take when you have availability groups and with logins, the SIDs have to be the same so they can fail over seamlessly.
And yes, if you are in the scenario where an Azure datacenter is completely down and you forcefully bring up the secondary node to be the primary, any application trying to connect to the secondary will fail since it's pointing at the completely down datacenter.
Personally, I've tried to get around this with using C-Names (as I would in an on-prem environment) but Azure Managed Instances really care about what they are called.  Setting up a C-Name lead to inability to login, which was really frustrating.  So in the event that our secondary actually went down, we would need to manually update any place that we have specified that.

I've tried using CNames as well. It doesn't work since Hosted SQL needs the "server name" on the url. You can get around this by specifying the user name as user@server but this defeats the purpose. If we have to specify the server on the user name, might as well specify it on the url.

Follow up question: Can I set up a third database as the failover for the read-replica? So that DBPrimary fails over to DBRead (which is now DBPrimary) and DBRead fails over to DBThird (which becomes DBRead) and DBPrimary (which is down) becomes DBThird?

I'd forgotten about the user@server trick, but yeah, that didn't make what I was trying to do work so that was a no go.  And no, failover groups only support pairs of servers.  Plus your pairs should be in the "paired" azure datacenters (like central is paired with east, etc.) so your options are limited.  BUT, in the event that an Azure datacenter is down, there will be so much chaos in your infrastructure that some manual steps are acceptable.

The only thing I would add is that if the read-only workload is referencing the server name, rather than the failover group name, then that workload would be unaffected by the failover operation. But at the end of the day, the read-only workload is unprotected by failover. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/339478/can-i-create-a-geo-replica-of-a-named-replica. It appears that you can have failover protection for your primary workload. You can also split off your read-only workload. But the read-only workload will not have failover protection.

I do have to point out at licensing, which is not directly related to this question. When you use secondary as read-only, you still have to fully license both SQL servers both primary and secondary nodes. Am I wrong?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The OP (at least in their choice of tags) indicated they were using Azure Managed Instances, which includes the license in their pricing model, so if you spin up a secondary to be in the failover group, you are paying for it to be used.  Your concern about needing to license the secondary if you are going to use it for anything but a hot spare is definitely valid for box/on-prem installations.
