Can I create a Geo Replica of a Named Replica?
For clarity, we have two databases on a server in a given region. One database is the primary for the read/write workload, and one is a replica for the read-only workload. I'm trying to set up a failover which will work for both workloads. So I'm trying to get the primary, as well as its named replica, replicated over to the standby server.
We're using Azure's hosted database (PaaS) service. We have a primary DB which handles our transactional workload. I created a Named Replica on the same server, to offload read-only workloads.
I also created a Geo Replica of the primary DB which is hosted on a separate server in a different region. I created a failover group which can swap my server back and forth between regions.
But now I'd like to have a Geo Replica of the Named Replica (the read-only DB on my primary server) so that when I go into failover mode, I can support both my transactional and read-only workloads. Is this possible? Seemingly, the only replica I can make is from the primary DB. I can't find any way to use the Named Replica as the base for a Geo Replica. Which leaves me in a catch-22. I can't create a second Geo Replicated database onto the failover server because there's already a database there by that name. I can't create a Named Replica onto the failover server because a Named Replica must be in the same region (which would be useless for failover purposes, anyway).
See the screenshot. In a nutshell, I am trying to get a replicated database named test_read onto my server r8standby in the South Central datacenter, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to set this up. Is this at all possible?


I was unable to find a way to do this. Certainly it does not appear to be supported through the Azure management console. I don't know that it is impossible to do through programmatic interface so I'm not going to mark this as the answer because it may in fact be possible. Here's what I ended up doing which satisfies 99.99% of our ambitions.
I created a failover cluster containing the primary and secondary server hosting the replica. I configured my processing workloads to use the primary endpoint for the failover cluster. I configured my read workloads to directly reference the secondary server. (The read workloads are not referencing the secondary endpoint on the failover cluster. The reason for this will become apparent below.)
Normal Conditions
Here is the representation of the system under normal processing conditions. Processing workloads are referencing the cluster's primary endpoint, which is pointing to the primary server. Read workloads are pointing directly to the secondary server (rather than the cluster's secondary endpoint) in South Central. The cluster's secondary endpoint is pointing to the secondary server, but we don't have any processes accessing that endpoint.

Failover Scenario
Here is the representation of the system under a failover condition. The server in the East Coast is unavailable and the server in South Central has been promoted to primary. Processing workloads are referencing the cluster's primary endpoint, which is now pointing to the newly promoted primary server in South Central. Read workloads are pointing to that same server in South Central. This is why we don't point our read workloads to the cluster's secondary endpoint. If we pointed our read workloads to the cluster's secondary endpoint, our read-workloads would go down in a failover scenario. While we're somewhat disadvantaged from a performance standpoint by having combined workloads all hitting the same server, this is preferable to us than losing the read workload entirely.

Unprotected Scenario
If the South Central datacenter goes down then we are going to lose our read-only workloads for the duration of the outage. This is simply a limitation of Azure's replication capabilities for its hosted database solution. What we'd like to have is our primary database replicated to a named replica in the same region (for workload distribution) and then both of those databases geo replicated out to a separate region so that all workloads, both processing loads and read-only loads can have failover. But this is just not possible. Because Azure does not allow a replica of a replica, there is no way to replicate a named replica out to a different geographic location. We will just have to live with this.

We will just have to live with this. This should be tolerable for several basic reasons:

This isn't worse than the database platform support we've had up to this point. We're not taking anything away because we've never had any redundancy in the past.

We're picking up a huge processing advantage by allocating our different workloads onto different servers. This advantage should be near perfect over 99.99% of production time, because this is Microsoft's SLA for its Azure database service.

The loss of the read workload is much easier to recover from than the loss of the processing workload. (For example - the loss of the read workload won't create a backlog.)


We're finding that this serves 99.99% of what we need.
